# Using ref() not reacting to reassignments - composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Here is a simple carousel:

```
<template>
    <div ref="wrapperRef" class="js-carousel container">
        <div class="row">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <template v-for="n in noOfSlides" :key="n">
                <span style="margin-right: 25px;" @click="console.log(n)">O</span>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

This works using Options API. **The `noOfSlides` is properly getting changed and the for-loop re-renders after mounting**

```
export default {
    name: 'carousel',
    data() {

        return {
            noOfSlides: 0
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.noOfSlides = this.$refs.wrapperRef.querySelectorAll('.js-carousel-item').length;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work while using composition API like below. **The `noOfSlides` is not getting changed and thus for-loop not re-rendering**

```
export default {
    name: 'carousel',
    setup() {
        const wrapperRef = ref(null);
        let noOfSlides = ref(0);



        onMounted(function () {
            noOfSlides = wrapperRef.value.querySelectorAll('.js-carousel-item').length;// this here properly returning the number of slides(more than 0 anyway)
        })

        return {
            wrapperRef,
            noOfSlides
        }
    }
}
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the Vue way to work with DOM, you could use `slots` :

```js
export default {
  name: 'carousel',
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    const wrapperRef = ref(null);
    let noOfSlides = ref(0);

    onMounted(function () {
      console.log('slots ', slots.default());
      noOfSlides.value = slots.default().length;
    });
    function log(n) {
      console.log('n ', n);
    }
    return {
      wrapperRef,
      noOfSlides,
      log,
    };
  },
};
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-uqphrm-wbrq4u?file=app.vue,Carousel.vue)

Comment: yes it was the issue

Comment: Recheck my edited answer, O suggested a better solution

Comment: I never thought `slots.default().length` would give the multiple children count since the parent is rendering all of them to a single slot. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, it's better to add check like `noOfSlides.value = slots.default?slots.default().length:0`